# Problem with django's call_command inside a Thread

Tags: python, django, multithreading, pyqt, pyside

I would to execute the django's call_method inside a Thread.
This is the sample code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/my/django/project/path/")
import threading
import time 


# Import my django project configuration settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from mydjangoprojectname import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from django.core.management import call_command

class ServerStarter(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ServerStarter, self).__init__()
        print "ServerStarter instance created"

    def run(self):
        print "Starting Django Server..."
        call_command("runserver", noreload=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    starter = ServerStarter()
    starter.start()

------------------------------
OutPut:
ServerStarter instance created
Starting Django Server...
ServerStarter instance created
Starting Django Server...
Validating models...
0 errors found
Django version 1.2.3, using settings 'mydjangoprojectname.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Django server starts correctly, but ServerStarter is created **twice**.
And both ServerStarter's instances run.
If I comment call_command("runserver", noreload=True) in the run method, then only
one thread is created (and that is what I want).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be aware that's not going to be a very nice way of doing it; what if port 8000 is taken? Or what if something else wants port 8000? At the very least, use a semi-random port number.

Comment: Same thing happens using `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably caused by the Django internal server reloading all modules as is its wont. Try whatever the equivalent of `--noreload` is for `call_command` (probably `call_command("runserver", noreload=True)` but I'm not sure).

(Also `QThread`s are started by `QApplication.exec_()`; unless you have a special requirement to start it earlier, I don't believe you should run `starter.start()` yourself.)

Comment: I've removed the GUI stuff from my question.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution (Chris Morgan was right). This code works as I want:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/my/django/project/path/")
import threading

# Import my django project configuration settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ, ManagementUtility

from mydjangoprojectname import settings
setup_environ(settings)


class ServerStarter(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ServerStarter, self).__init__()
        print "ServerStarter instance created"

    def run(self):
        print "Starting Django Server..."
        utility = ManagementUtility()
        command = utility.fetch_command('runserver')
        command.execute(use_reloader=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    starter = ServerStarter()
    starter.start()
```